# Edit equations with both MSWord on Windows and Mac

Tags: ms-office

I have a Word document with lots of equations in it. I created it on the Mac. I edited it on Windows. All of the equations got turned into bitmaps. This seems like poor behavior. Is there a way to turn them back? Is there a proper way to embed equations in a Word document to avoid this problem?

I know I should just be using \LaTeX, but my collaborators don't want to.

Comment: Have you also tried the word forums?  Very important always to also tell everyone what version of Word you are using.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac

Comment: Use this site: http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor to write equations in latex and convert them to pictures (.gif,.png...) and further embed in Word

Comment: Pictures that are embedded are not line art.